# Could an IGBT gate driver be used to drive a SiC MOSFET?

Tags: power-electronics, inverter, gate-driving, igbt, sic

Can we use a single channel HV IGBT gate driver with galvanic isolation which is previously mounted to derive a 1200V IGBT for 800V inverter application?  Can the same gate driver drive a 1200V SiC device considering SiC MOSFETS need -5V for safe turn off operation due to very low VGSth? If we use an IGBT gate driver to derive a SiC FET, what are the pros and cons of such activity?

Comment: I've done the very same thing.

Comment: could you please eloborate and share your experience

Comment: Not really because there is IP involved and, remember that this is a question and answer site.

Comment: ok but can you share some tips for me what are the things which I should consider? the problem i see is that ususally the igbt gate driver has same source and sink current capability however for sic fet we need higher sink current as we have to pull down the gate below ground typically at -5V so how to tackle this issue?

Comment: You should share the schematic of the IGBT gate driver that was previously used for driving a 1200 volt IGBT.

Comment: You can use several tricks to level shift your way down to -5 V as reference. Check the application notes and do a search.